# Solving exponential system of equations

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve equation:

`Solve[{y1 == -a*Exp[-b*x1], y2 == -a*Exp[-b*x2]}, {a, b}]`

using `Solve` method but I receive error:
`Solve::ivar: E^kb t is not a valid variable.`I am not reallty sure why I receive this kind of error and how can I make mathematica solve this equation.

Comment: Maybe you had a prior definition such as `a=t*Exp[kb]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works.

```
Solve[{y1 == -a*Exp[-b*x1], y2 == -a*Exp[-b*x2]}, {a, b}, Reals]
```

> {{a->ConditionalExpression[-y1 (y1/y2)^(-(x1/(x1-x2))),(y1>0&&y2>0)||(y1<0&&y2<0)],b->ConditionalExpression[-(Log[y1/y2]/(x1-x2)),(y1>0&&y2>0)||(y1<0&&y2<0)]}}